# How to clear \listoffigures between different parts of the document?

Tags: table-of-contents

Since I'm required to write a document in multiple languages, is it possible to reset the list of figures/tables at different parts of the document?

The first two languages are not required to have a list of figures, therefore I just need to discard the list once, before the last one.

I can reset the counter with:

```
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\setcounter{listing}{0}
```

However, in the final `\listoffigures` all figures will show up.

I can add arbitrary content to the `.lof` file with `\addcontentsline`, however I haven't found a corresponding `\clearcontents` function.

Alternatively, I've thought of rendering the three theses separately, and then merging the PDFs, but that feels hackish.

Comment: can you please add a minimale example of your code? you can do this see [titletoc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package.

Comment: This is not so easy with standard methods, since there's only one `.lof` file usually per run.

Comment: I agree with @touhami... could we have some more context? Currently things aren't very clear.

Comment: @Werner Sorry if I was unclear, Christian's solution is what I was looking for.

Comment: One might be able to create multiple float types, one for each language.  The name of the float/counter does not have to appear in the caption or listof...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: See the better versions at the of the code, the basic principles explained at the top did not change, however!

A really quick hack, that hooks into `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`, advancing a counter for each `\listof...` and writing the entries to `1lof`, `2lof`, etc. (the same for `1lot`, etc.)

This is done by redefining the `\ext@lof` etc. command each time a `\caption` is used.

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcounter{lofcntr}
\newcounter{lotcntr}


\newcommand{\clearcontents}{%
  \stepcounter{lofcntr}%
  \stepcounter{lotcntr}%
  \setcounter{figure}{0}
  \setcounter{table}{0}
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \stepcounter{lofcntr}%
  \stepcounter{lotcntr}%
}


\makeatletter

\xpretocmd{\caption}{%
  \def\ext@figure{\number\value{lofcntr}lof}
  \def\ext@table{\number\value{lotcntr}lot}
}{\typeout{Worked!}}{}



\xpatchcmd{\listoffigures}{%
  \@starttoc{lof}%
}{%
  \@starttoc{\number\value{lofcntr}lof}%
}{\typeout{Patch success}}{\typeout{Patch failure}}

\xpatchcmd{\listoftables}{%
  \@starttoc{lot}%
}{%
  \@starttoc{\number\value{lotcntr}lot}%
}{\typeout{Patch success}}{\typeout{Patch failure}}

\makeatother




\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption}

\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption}


\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 1st lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 1st lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 1st lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 1st lot}


\clearcontents

\listoffigures
\listoftables


\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 2nd lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 2nd lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 2nd lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 2nd lof}


\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 2nd lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 2nd lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 2nd lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 2nd lot}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** Some better version:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}


% Do not a driver counter, i.e. a resetting counter for those two counter fellows here:
\newcounter{lofcntr}
\newcounter{lotcntr}


\NewDocumentCommand{\clearcontents}{}{%
  \stepcounter{lofcntr}% We don't need labels here, I suppose?
  \stepcounter{lotcntr}%
  \setcounter{figure}{0}
  \setcounter{table}{0}
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \stepcounter{lofcntr}% 
  \stepcounter{lotcntr}%
}


\makeatletter
% Store the definition of \ext@figure etc. first
\let\latex@ext@figure\ext@figure
\let\latex@ext@table\ext@table

\AtBeginDocument{%
\xpretocmd{\caption}{%
  % Prepend the extension with the number of the current list of ...
  \def\ext@figure{\number\value{lofcntr}\latex@ext@figure}
  \def\ext@table{\number\value{lotcntr}\latex@ext@table}
}{\typeout{Worked!}}{\typeout{Failed miserably!}}
}


\xpatchcmd{\listoffigures}{%
  \@starttoc{lof}%
}{%
  \@starttoc{\number\value{lofcntr}lof}%
}{\typeout{Patch success}}{\typeout{Patch failure}}

\xpatchcmd{\listoftables}{%
  \@starttoc{lot}%
}{%
  \@starttoc{\number\value{lotcntr}lot}%
}{\typeout{Patch success}}{\typeout{Patch failure}}

\makeatother



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables


\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 1st lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 1st lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 1st lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 1st lof}

\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 1st lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 1st lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 1st lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 1st lot}

\clearcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables


\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 2nd lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 2nd lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 2nd lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 2nd lof}


\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 2nd lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 2nd lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 2nd lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 2nd lot}



\end{document}
```

**Update** for `minted` and `listings` environment:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}


% Do not use a driver counter, i.e. a resetting counter for those two counter fellows here:
\newcounter{lofcntr}
\newcounter{lotcntr}
\newcounter{lolcntr}

\NewDocumentCommand{\clearcontents}{}{%
  \stepcounter{lofcntr}% We don't need labels here, I suppose?
  \stepcounter{lotcntr}%
  \stepcounter{lolcntr}%
  \setcounter{figure}{0}
  \setcounter{table}{0}
  \setcounter{listing}{0}
}


\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\advancecontents}{}{%
  \def\ext@figure{\number\value{lofcntr}\latex@ext@figure}
  \def\ext@table{\number\value{lotcntr}\latex@ext@table}%
  \@namedef{ext@listing}{\number\value{lolcntr}\latex@ext@listing}%
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
% Store the definition of \ext@figure etc. first
  \let\latex@ext@figure\ext@figure
  \let\latex@ext@table\ext@table
  \let\latex@ext@listing\ext@listing
  \stepcounter{lofcntr}% 
  \stepcounter{lotcntr}%
  \stepcounter{lolcntr}%
  \advancecontents%
}



\AtBeginDocument{%
\xpretocmd{\caption}{%
  % Prepend the extension with the number of the current list of ...
  \advancecontents%
}{\typeout{Patching caption worked!}}{\typeout{Patching caption failed miserably!}}
}



\xpatchcmd{\listoffigures}{%
  \@starttoc{lof}%
}{%
  \@starttoc{\number\value{lofcntr}lof}%
}{\typeout{Patch success}}{\typeout{Patch failure}}

\xpatchcmd{\listoftables}{%
  \@starttoc{lot}%
}{%
  \@starttoc{\number\value{lotcntr}lot}%
}{\typeout{Patch success}}{\typeout{Patch failure}}


\makeatother



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\listoflistings


\begin{listing}
  \mint{c}
  /* code */
  \caption{A foo listing for 1st lol}
\end{listing}


\begin{listing}
  \mint{c}
  /* code */
  \caption{A foo listing for 1st lol}
\end{listing}

\begin{listing}
  \mint{c}
  /* code */
  \caption{A foo listing for 1st lol}
\end{listing}

\begin{listing}
  \mint{c}
  /* code */
  \caption{A foo listing for 1st lol}
\end{listing}



\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 1st lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 1st lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 1st lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 1st lof}

\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 1st lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 1st lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 1st lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 1st lot}

\clearcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\listoflistings

\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 2nd lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 2nd lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 2nd lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 2nd lof}


\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 2nd lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 2nd lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 2nd lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 2nd lot}


\begin{listing}
  \mint{c}
  /* code */
  \caption{A foo listing for 2nd lol}
\end{listing}

\begin{listing}
  \mint{c}
  /* code */
  \caption{A foo listing for 2nd lol}
\end{listing}

\begin{listing}
  \mint{c}
  /* code */
  \caption{A foo listing for 2nd lol}
\end{listing}


\end{document}
```

Comment: the redefinition of `\ext@figure` deserves some rework, of course, but I had no time ;-)

Comment: @RoliSoft: You're welcome. I will update with a better version later on

Comment: I'm trying to adapt it for use with `listing`/minted, however I'm getting "Patch failure" on `\xpatchcmd{\listoflistings}`. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @RoliSoft: `\listoflistings` is defined differently. You can't apply the same scheme for anything. I'll take a look

Comment: In minted, `\listoflistings` is defined as `\providecommand{\listoflistings}{\listof{listing}{\listoflistingscaption}}`, if that helps.

Comment: @RoliSoft: You're really using the `minted` package?

Comment: Yes. This is how I insert a new code fragment: `\begin{listing}\begin{minted}{c}/* code */\end{minted}\caption{...}\label{...}\end{listing}`

Comment: @RoliSoft: I'll check. Should be similar, anyway

Comment: @RoliSoft: The good message: `\ext@listing` does exist ;-)

Comment: @RoliSoft: I've updated with a working solution, I think

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Great solution! But how can I make it work with `scrbook` instead of `book`?

Comment: @LukasCB: No solution for `scrbook` from me -- I am no KOMA user

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Too bad, the "only" thing not working is the patching since it renames the list to "List of 3lof" etc and starts a new page.

Comment: @LukasCB: Blame KOMA for that ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The following example (starting point was Christian Hupfer's example) defines a switch for each language `\ifLangA`, `\ifLangB`. When the part for a language *X* starts, then `\ifLangX` is written to the auxiliary files `.lof` and `.lot` and the closing `\fi` is added there at the end of the language part. When the list of figures and tables are set, only the current language part is enabled by the switch and the other entries are ignored.

When LaTeX sets the `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` it clears the auxiliary files `.lof` and `.lot` after the list is output. This is prevented by locally setting `\@fileswfalse`, an internal switch, which tells LaTeX not to touch and write the auxiliary files (used by `\nofiles`).
Only the last lists of figures and tables are set normally.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\newif\ifLangA
\newif\ifLangB

\newcommand*{\StartLang}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{%
    \expandafter\protect\csname ifLang#1\endcsname
  }%
  \addtocontents{lot}{%
    \expandafter\protect\csname ifLang#1\endcsname
  }%
  \csname Lang#1true\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\LangFalse\csname Lang#1false\endcsname
}
\newcommand*{\StopLang}{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\fi}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\fi}%
  \LangFalse
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ListOfFigures}{%
  \begingroup
    \@fileswfalse
    \listoffigures
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\ListOfTables}{%
  \begingroup
    \@fileswfalse
    \listoftables
  \endgroup
}
\let\LastListOfFigures\listoffigures
\let\LastListOfTables\listoftables
\makeatother

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\StartLang{A}

  \chapter{Lang A}

  \ListOfFigures
  \ListOfTables

  \captionof{figure}{Some figure caption}

  \captionof{figure}{Some figure caption}
  \captionof{figure}{Some figure caption}
  \captionof{figure}{Some figure caption}

  \captionof{table}{Some table caption for 1st lot}
  \captionof{table}{Some table caption for 1st lot}
  \captionof{table}{Some table caption for 1st lot}
  \captionof{table}{Some table caption for 1st lot}

\StopLang

\StartLang{B}

  \chapter{Lang B}

  \LastListOfFigures
  \LastListOfTables

  \captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 2nd lof}
  \captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 2nd lof}
  \captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 2nd lof}
  \captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 2nd lof}

  \captionof{table}{Some table caption for 2nd lot}
  \captionof{table}{Some table caption for 2nd lot}
  \captionof{table}{Some table caption for 2nd lot}
  \captionof{table}{Some table caption for 2nd lot}

\StopLang

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is 3 methods

---

1 without any package just `\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\clearlist}` in the OP way

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newcommand{\clearlist}{%
\begingroup
\renewcommand\addvspace[1]{}
\renewcommand\contentsline[3]{}}  % replace 3 with 4 if hyperref used
\newcommand{\resetlist}{\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\clearlist}
\chapter{foo}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image}
\caption{Foo}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image}
\caption{Foo}
\end{figure}

\chapter{bar}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image}
\caption{Foo}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image}
\caption{Foo}
\end{figure}

\chapter{baz}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\resetlist}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image}
\caption{Foo}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image}
\caption{Foo}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

2 using [titletoc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package with commands

```
\startlist{lof}
\printlist{lof}{}{%
\renewcommand\addvspace[1]{}}
```

and `\stoplist{lof}`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image}
\caption{Foo1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image}
\caption{Foo2}
\end{figure}

\chapter{bar}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image}
\caption{Foo3}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image}
\caption{Foo4}
\end{figure}

\chapter{baz}
\startlist{lof}
\printlist{lof}{}{%
\renewcommand\addvspace[1]{}% % more stuff can be add here to customize the list
}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image}
\caption{Foo5}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image}
\caption{Foo6}
\end{figure}
\stoplist{lof}
\end{document}
```

---

3 using [minitoc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) package

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{minitoc}
\dominilof
\AtEndDocument{\listoffigures}%   % comment this line in last run
\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image}
\caption{Foo1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image}
\caption{Foo2}
\end{figure}

\chapter{bar}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image}
\caption{Foo3}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image}
\caption{Foo4}
\end{figure}

\chapter{baz}
\minilof
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image}
\caption{Foo5}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image}
\caption{Foo6}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Note** one need to use `\listoffigures` some where (at end of document) and comment it in last run or just save it in a savebox.

Comment: I ended up using your first method due to its simplicity and universal applicability to any toc file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `tocbasic` package that is part of the KOMA-script classes to create your own list-of-things. See Chapter 15 in the KOMA-script manual.

Here is a MWE that assumes you are using the KOMA `scrreprt` class and want a list of figures for each chapter. In the preamble I define a new type of float called `figure1` for figures in chapter 1 and a similar one called `figure2` for figures in chapter 2 using `tocbasic`'s `\DeclareNewTOC` function. These floats behave like regular figures (`floattype=1`). (Maybe this can be automated somehow to get automatic numbering for each chapter...)
The corresponding listof lists  are named `lof1` and `lof2`. The actual listof is inserted in the document using `\listoftoc{lof1}`, `\listoftoc{lof2}`, etc. Using the class option `listof=totoc` adds the two listof entries to the table of contents.
[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\DeclareNewTOC[%
   type=figure1,%
   float,% define a floating environment
   floattype=1,%
   counterwithin=chapter,%
   name=Figure,%
   listname={List of Figures for Chapter 1}%
]{lof1}

\DeclareNewTOC[%
   type=figure2,%
   float,% define a floating environment
   floattype=1,%
   counterwithin=chapter,%
   name=Figure,%
   listname={List of Figures for Chapter 2}%
]{lof2}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\label{cha:achapter}
\begin{figure1}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{}
  \caption{A figure in the first chapter}
  \label{fig:achapter}
\end{figure1}

\listoftoc{lof1}

\chapter{Another chapter}
\label{cha:another-chapter}
\begin{figure2}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{}
  \caption{A figure in the second chapter}
  \label{fig:anotherchapter}
\end{figure2}

\listoftoc{lof2}

\end{document}
```

If you don't use one of the KOMA classes, add `\usepackage{scrhack,tocbasic}` to your preamble.

Answer (score 1):

What can I say?  It's an interesting problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

\newfloat{german}{tbp}{lofg}
\floatname{german}{Figur}

\begin{document}

\captionof{figure}{English}
\captionof{german}{Deutsch}

\listoffigures

\listof{german}{Liste Figuren}

\end{document}
```