# How to have several list of figures (LoF) with KOMA?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, xpatch

There ist a great answer and solution to this question by [Christian Hupfer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/311839/98739), *BUT* it does not work with `KOMA-Script`which is a pity.

The question is how to get several `listof` in one document?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}


% Do not a driver counter, i.e. a resetting counter for those two counter fellows here:
\newcounter{lofcntr}
\newcounter{lotcntr}


\NewDocumentCommand{\clearcontents}{}{%
  \stepcounter{lofcntr}% We don't need labels here, I suppose?
  \stepcounter{lotcntr}%
  \setcounter{figure}{0}
  \setcounter{table}{0}
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \stepcounter{lofcntr}% 
  \stepcounter{lotcntr}%
}


\makeatletter
% Store the definition of \ext@figure etc. first
\let\latex@ext@figure\ext@figure
\let\latex@ext@table\ext@table

\AtBeginDocument{%
\xpretocmd{\caption}{%
  % Prepend the extension with the number of the current list of ...
  \def\ext@figure{\number\value{lofcntr}\latex@ext@figure}
  \def\ext@table{\number\value{lotcntr}\latex@ext@table}
}{\typeout{Worked!}}{\typeout{Failed miserably!}}
}


\xpatchcmd{\listoffigures}{%
  \@starttoc{lof}%
}{%
  \@starttoc{\number\value{lofcntr}lof}%
}{\typeout{Patch success}}{\typeout{Patch failure}}

\xpatchcmd{\listoftables}{%
  \@starttoc{lot}%
}{%
  \@starttoc{\number\value{lotcntr}lot}%
}{\typeout{Patch success}}{\typeout{Patch failure}}

\makeatother



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables


\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 1st lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 1st lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 1st lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 1st lof}

\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 1st lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 1st lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 1st lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 1st lot}

\clearcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables


\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 2nd lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 2nd lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 2nd lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 2nd lof}


\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 2nd lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 2nd lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 2nd lot}
\captionof{table}{Some table caption for 2nd lot}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the names of the lists are not display correctly and set to a new page (common behaviour?!):
[image]

[image]

> Is it possible to get rid of the heading at all and that it won't start on a new page?

---

*Edit:* I’d be happy to work with a different code as well. At least it works with `KOMA` and is as easy to adopt as the one above.

Comment: Why don't you use `\DeclareNewTOC` to define another LoF with another extension? Then you can either change `\ext@figure` or you can define another figure environment using option `float` of `\DeclareNewTOC`. Something like this has been shown in: [Mit einem aktuellen KOMA-Script geht alles viel einfacher](https://komascript.de/comment/5578#comment-5578) for a separate appendix LoF (and LoT and ToC).

Comment: @Schweinebacke Thanks for the link. This looked promising but as far as I see it requires to create a new `DeclareNewTOC` for each `listoffigures`. Since I will have numerous `listoffigures` that approach looks like too much manual work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using both the linked [answer by Christian](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/311839/98739) and the [suggestion on the `KOMA-Script` website for additional LoFs](https://komascript.de/comment/5578#comment-5578). If the LoF should not start a new page it should not be chapter. So you have to use option `listof=leveldown`.

```
\documentclass[%
  listof=totoc,% ToC entry for all LoFs and similar lists
  listof=leveldown]% LoF and similar lists as section instead chapter
{scrbook}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\newcounter{lofcntr}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\clearlof}{}{%
  \stepcounter{lofcntr}%
  \setcounter{figure}{0}%
  \DeclareNewTOC
    [listname=\protect\listfigurename]
    {\number\value{lofcntr}lof}%
  \renewcommand*{\ext@figure}{\number\value{lofcntr}lof}%
}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{\clearlof}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\listoffigures
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 1st lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 1st lof}

\chapter{Secound Chapter}
\clearlof
\listoffigures
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 2nd lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 2nd lof}

\chapter{Third Chapter}
\clearlof
\listoffigures
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 3nd lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 3nd lof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

But if you need more than 12 additional LoFs you will get the

> No room for a new `\write`.

error. Note, that your MWE has the same limitation even if a standard class is used.

If you need more LoFs you can load `KOMA-Script` package `scrwfile` (alpha-status).

```
\documentclass[
  listof=totoc,% ToC entry for all LoFs and similar lists
  listof=leveldown% LoF and similar lists as section instead chapter
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{scrwfile}% if there are more than 12 additional aux files needed
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\newcounter{lofcntr}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\clearlof}{}{%
  \stepcounter{lofcntr}%
  \setcounter{figure}{0}%
  \DeclareNewTOC
    [listname=\protect\listfigurename]
    {\number\value{lofcntr}lof}%
  \renewcommand*{\ext@figure}{\number\value{lofcntr}lof}%
}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{\clearlof}% then the default lof is not used

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\examplelofs{m}% only for dummy LoFs
  {
    \int_do_until:nNnn
      {\value{lofcntr}} = {#1}
      {
        \chapter{A~chapter}
        \clearlof
        \listoffigures
        \captionof{figure}{Some~figure~caption~for~\number\value{lofcntr}nd~lof}
        \captionof{figure}{Some~figure~caption~for~\number\value{lofcntr}nd~lof}
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\listoffigures
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 1st lof}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure caption for 1st lof}

\examplelofs{20}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! That works fine. However as I found out with `\usepackage{morewrites}` I could do more than 40 individual `lof`. Is that not a recommended workflow? EDIT: It seems like `\usepackage{scrwfile}` is loaded by default?!

Comment: `scrwfile` is not loaded by default, but it is part of the KOMA-Script bundle. Maybe package `morewrites` is an alternative to `scrwfile`.