# How to let table of contents only include the second half of the document?

Tags: table-of-contents

Suppose my document has five sections, that is section 1 to section 5. I only want to add one table of contents to the last three sections, that is section 3 to section 5. How can I exclude section 1 and section 2 to show in my table of contents(I prefer to put the table of contents command right before section 3, while section 1 and section 2 still appear in my table of contents)?

Comment: If you don't need numbering the section 1 and 2, simply use `\section*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a variation of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/311859/ you can switch off the TOC entries for the first two sections by adding `\iffalse` and `\fi` around them with `\addtocontents`. The sections themselves, including numbering and referencing, are not affected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\iffalse}
\section{First}
\section{Second}
\label{secsecond}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\fi}
\tableofcontents
\section{Third}
Also read Section \ref{secsecond}.
\section{Fourth}
\section{Fifth}
\end{document}
```

Resulting `.toc` file:

```
\iffalse 
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}First}{1}{}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}Second}{1}{}%
\fi 
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3}Third}{1}{}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4}Fourth}{1}{}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {5}Fifth}{1}{}%
```

Compiled document:

[image]